# Google Sheets - Identify duplicates and overwriting data

Tags: google-apps-script

I've heavily edited the original question I posted, as i have solved some of the issue myself. I'm now stuck on just one thing.

```
function payINVOICE() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ds = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14imcEob2qIZbH6AjGYtf16MJxbnfkhQn1ae4jR-Nzq4");
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("INVOICE_ENTRY");
  var dstSheet = ds.getSheetByName("INVOICE_ENTRY");

  var data_range = srcSheet.getRange('B4:J100'); 
  var data_data = data_range.getValues();
  var data_clean  = data_data.filter(function (r) {return r[1]});

  var clear_range = srcSheet.getRange('B4:I100');



  var lr = dstSheet.getLastRow(); 

  dstSheet.getRange(lr+1, 2,data_clean.length,9).setValues(data_clean);
  clear_range.clear();

}
```

This code checks the range B4:J100 for a value in Column B. 
If there is a value and the script is run, it copies those rows onto dstSheet.

My role is marking invoices as paid or not.
The dstSheet will already contain the data, which is pulled back into the srcSheet with a query. Column K is not part of the original query.
If I mark a row as "PAID" in column K on the srcSheet, I want the code to take the data_data variable and overwrite what is already in the dstSheet, so that the query then pulls the data back into srcSheet with column J then showing "PAID".

It means I can then change column K to "NOT PAID", run the script again and it will over-write the "PAID".

This makes better sense than my last post and I am so close to achieving what I need, just stuck on this last bit.

Comment: Hey there @mancstu, what exactly is your goal here? Would you mind being more specific and providing more information about what are you trying to achieve? For example, which duplicates from which sheet you want to identify?

Comment: Hey ale13! I've added comments to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to monitor the changes between the two mentioned sheets, it would be much easier to use an `onEdit(e)` trigger which will tell you which cell has been edited.

#### Snippet

```
function payINVOICE(e) {
  var srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //gets the active sheet which is supposed to be source sheet
  var dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('DEST_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('INVOICE_ENTRY'); //gets the destination sheet 
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'INVOICE_ENTRY' && e.range.getColumn() == 11) { //e specifies where the edit has been made - therefore this if condition checks if the edit is in the INVOICE ENTRY sheet and if the column is the K column
     var row =e.range.getRow(); //this gathers the row at which the edit has been made
     var data = srcSheet.getRange(row, 2, 1, 10).getValues(); //this gathers the data corresponding to the row at which the edit has been made 
     dstSheet.getRange(row, 2, 1, 10).setValues(data); //this sets the data into the corresponding row in the destination sheet
}
```

#### Explanation

The above code uses the `onEdit(e)` installable trigger and the `e` event object. In this way, when an edit is being made on the `srcSheet` on the `11th` column (aka `K` column) *and* the sheet name is `"INVOICE_ENTRY"`, then the `row` at which the change has been made is kept in the `row` variable. Afterwards, the corresponding row of data is kept in the `data` variable; the `getRange(row, 2, 1, 10)` references the range for the row at which the change on the `K` column has been made. In order to update the `dstSheet`, the `data` value is set to the according range using `setValues(data)`.

#### Installing the trigger

To make the `payINVOICE(e)` function trigger on an edit action, you need to install an `onEdit` trigger.

This is being done by accessing the project's triggers by clicking this icon:

[image: current project triggers]

After that, you just need to create a new trigger by clicking the **Add trigger** button and create a trigger with the following settings:

[image: add the trigger]

#### Trying the function

In order to try the behavior for this, you just need to make an edit on the `srcSheet` on the `K` column and this change will be reflected in the `destSheet`.

#### Note

The ranges that have been used in this script are chosen considering the fact that:

- `K` column consists of the `PAID`/`NOT PAID` text;
- The `srcSheet` and the `dstSheet` have the data wanted in the same ranges.

You might need to customize these according to your sheet and add the needed formulas/filters you have mentioned.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

Comment: Thank-you @ale13. Didn't expect you to go to this much trouble. Have to say that I'm finding your explanation more helpful than the code itself, although appreciate the code as well. Many thanks.

Comment: Hey @mancstu, I added some explanation on the code. Let me know if it is much clearer and/or have any questions regarding it. Cheers!